# Using MapProxy in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, wms, mapproxy

I'm trying to print a layout in QGIS that contain the WMS cartography of IGM, but each time I try there's a different hole in the result.
I discovered that MapProxy can do the trick, downloading the cache before the printing.

So, I ask you how to use MapProxy in QGIS to obtain the result and/or if there is a better way to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You set up Mapproxy and expose the wms function as a cache for IGM. To make sure you dont get any holes I suggest that you create the complete cache by seeding it first. The documentation at the website is quite clear on how.

After that you can consume the wms-service just as any other wms in QGis